# Drupal sidebar formatting issue

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

The Drupal 6 website I am working on is giving me some problems with the sidebars.

Here, my 'general info' sidebar is incorrectly showing 'home' sidebar info.

To the right is my 'divisions' sidebar which displays correctly [except for the >> next to probate, can't seem to find a fix for that issue]

[image: apppeals sidebar]
[image: general info sidebar]

I've tried to go through general info and compare the node hierarchy with that of divisions, making sure the settings are similar. I did not seem to find anything that would fix the issue for me.

Also if anyone could help me with why the ">>" 's show up seemingly randomly ( see 'Human Resources', 'Juvenile Delinquency Court', and 'Records management') These nodes do not have children.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that the double arrows represent nodes with children. Without being able to browse your site its difficult to confirm or comment on your other issue.

Comment: http://dev.sjcourts.org/human-resources is the page in question. The only node with children is the Human Resources page. Another good example of left navigation bar wackiness is on page http://dev.sjcourts.org/appeals where the general info nav is expanded for some reason and all of it's children have double arrows.